# Is the use of past tense as "let me know if you needed" common?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Here is a literally-quoted [passage](http://books.google.com/books?id=YtfyBo4CrY0C&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=My+pleasure.+Go+back+to+rest+and+sleep.+Let+me+know+if+you+needed+something&source=bl&ots=6FPejaRb9x&sig=ufh3-59xtoCoRQY1qyLdjYGJlG8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EhP_T9zhMsL_qwGljbWLCQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=My%20pleasure.%20Go%20back%20to%20rest%20and%20sleep.%20Let%20me%20know%20if%20you%20needed%20something&f=false)  from ***Martyrs in Paradise: Woman of Mass Destruction*** by Terry Reese Downing:

> "How nice of you. And thank you," she again was appreciative.
>   "My pleasure. Go back to rest and sleep. Let me know if you **needed** something and don't hesitate to wake me up," he told her.

Is the use of past tense common in these kind of contexts? Does the use of past here get the point across in a less direct way?

Comment: It's certainly odd. What is the book and who is the writer?

Comment: @BarrieEngland- *Martyrs in Paradise:Woman of Mass Destruction By Terry Reese Downing.* I am not sure if the author is a native English speaker. And I don't know if that would make any difference, either.

Comment: Downing's "About the Author" section at [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Martyrs-Paradise-Woman-Destruction-ebook/dp/B0064OQ5GY) says 
"Born in the Philippines 10 years after World War II, Terry would hear nothing but stories of the war as a boy. And 24 more years before moving permanently to the USA, he had mingled and participated in that country's different tribes, factions and politics."  So he might or might not be a native English speaker.  However, it seems clear he is not a native English *writer*, with that sorry "she again was appreciative" line.

Comment: It would valid syntax in "You should have let me know if you needed something", but not in the sentence above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's wrong. It should be present tense *need*. I suspect the speaker has been misled☟ by the usual clueless nonsense about English having a subjunctive mood.

Students are often told in school that one must "use the subjunctive" in hypothetical clauses. Many interpret this command to mean that, since the verb *needed* in

- *If I **needed** anything, I would certainly tell you*.

is an example of "subjunctive", then past tense must be what one should use with *if*.

☝(when I was young, I always pronounced this word /'mayzəld/ when I read it; /mɪs'lɛd/ never occurred to me. Too bad -- *misle* would be a useful word)

Comment: This has nothing to do with any putative subjunctive mood.

Comment: You got a better hypothesis?

Comment: Fair question: my hypothesis is that it’s a simple error that was missed by the proofreader. My reasoning is that the languages with a distinct subjunctive inflection would take present not past subjunctive there. Past subjunctive triggers when the other clause is in the conditional, not the imperative. Mood aside, the whole sequence of tenses is off with "IMPERATIVE if PAST" rather than "IMPERATIVE if PRESENT". I guess something like "Let me know if you ate something poisonous" is just barely plausible, but not very likely.

Comment: Regarding sequence of tenses and neighboring languages, French and Spanish have "IMPERATIVE if PRESENT-INDICATIVE", just like English has. Portuguese alone has the exotic "IMPERATIVE if FUTURE-SUBJUNCTIVE". French has "If IMPERFECT-INDICATIVE, then CONDITIONAL", where Spanish, Italian, and Portuguese all have "If IMPERFECT-SUBJUNCTIVE, then CONDITIONAL". It’s this last that you must have been thinking of, John, but I do not think it applies in this instance.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't being anywhere near this international. I don't think it has anything to do with real subjunctives in other languages. And I wasn't concerned with proofreading, but with the source of the 'simple error'. Why would anybody use a past tense verb in English in a situation where they're talking about the future? My best guess is that hypothetical clauses make educated Anglophones nervous because there's sposta be something special about the verb. Most don't understand the hypothetical/counterfactual distinction, look for a funny form to use, and past pops up.

Comment: @JohnLawler- Thank you for the answer. Suppose I have an interview tomorrow: *I will give you a ring after the interview and will let you know how it ***went****. I know it's a different construction, but I would to love to get your take on it as it's still using past in the future.

Comment: Because in the future, after the interview, is the reference time for the subordinate clause, and the interview is past relative to the call. The original sentence would have been grammatical if the speaker had meant to call and complain about things that had been needed but were not available. However, that's clearly not what was intended.

Comment: @JohnLawler- so what you are saying is that *I will give you a ring after the interview and will let you know how it went.* is not grammatical?

Comment: No, it's grammatical; I guess I didn't make that clear -- sorry. It **is** grammatical, for the reasons I gave.

Comment: @JohnLawler- If I just want to inform the person of how my interview **went** in general, I shouldn't  use **went**. I am rather confused, what is the difference between: **will let you know how it went** and **will let you know how it goes**?

Comment: @Noah: There's rarely a situation where one **must** use one tense or another. If you're going to be informal enough to omit the subject (e.g, _will_ vs _I will_), you really shouldn't worry about what tense to use. Either one is fine; they have slightly different subtle shades of temporality, but in this case there's really not any difference.

Comment: No, not really. Although saying "I will" instead of "I'll" is extremely formal, even in writing.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Why do you say subjunctive is fake science? Seen many talking about it, eg https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/07/17/need-grammar/

Comment: and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/conditionals-if

Comment: add "Dan would help you if you asked him." https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/es/english-grammar/will-or-would

Answer (score 1):

It’s not what I’d expect from a native speaker. It seems as if the writer was thinking of something like *You wouldn’t hesitate to wake me up if you needed something, would you?* but got confused in putting it down.

Answer (score 0):

The word "needed" seems incorrect here, it should be "need". It doesn't make sense to ask someone to let them know (in the future) that they needed something (in the past).

You could use "needed" in a conditional:

> "I assume you'd let me know if you needed anything."

Answer (score 0):

Folling *if*, the simple past temse relates to the future but indicates that, in the view of the speaker, the event us rather unlikely.

I could say 'If you *go* to the party, you might meet XX'. However, if you first indicate reluctance to go to the party, I would probably say 'If you *went* to the party...'

Perhaps the speaker in the example given is supposed to think the other is unlikely to want anything. That said, it certainly seems a very unusual and rather clumsy construction in this instance; it seems rather inhospitable to imply that the other party is expected not to need anything.